# TextToSpeech.setEngineByPackageName() doesn't set anything

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Following the tip in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048173/636571), I placed a call to *setEngineByPackageName* right in `onActivityResult()`, when `requestCode == REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK && TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS`:

```
  tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
  tts.setEngineByPackageName("com.ivona.tts.voicebeta.eng.usa.kendra");
```

But regardless whether I check or uncheck the `Always use my settings` in Text-to-speech settings, I always get the **pico** default engine!

Yes, I intentionally set the pico engine to be the default, so that I can test overriding it by the [aforementioned tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048173/636571). But that API method seems not to be working at all, or...  am I missing something?

(I know that *setEngineByPackageName* is deprecated, since it doesn't inform caller when the TTS engine has been initialized, but I need to support API 8, so this method is my only option at the moment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you placed the call to setEngineByPackageName in `onActivityResult()`. This is the wrong place to do this.

setEngineByPackageName, just like getDefaultEngine, must not be called before reaching `onInit()`.