# TextToSpeech.setEngineByPackageName() returns success even when package is not available

Tags: android, text-to-speech

After managing to make TextToSpeech.setEngineByPackageName() work thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476122/636571), I am now having the "opposite" problem:

`tts.setEngineByPackageName("com.ivona.tts.voicebeta.eng.usa.kendra");` always returns **TextToSpeech.SUCCESS**, even when that package is not installed at all in the device.

Since the package is not available on the device, TTS proceeds to speak with Android's default `pico`, which is expected, but I don't understand why `setEngineByPackageName()` returns SUCCESS.

How could this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the benefit of all, I am posting the answer provided by [@Nikolay Elenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493035/636571) on a different (but related) question:

Calling setEngineByPackageName() when the package doesn't exists is not a good idea. Instead, check if it is installed and **don't try to use it if it's not installed**:

```
boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName) {
  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  try {
    PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);

    return pi != null;
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

A good example of how this is done can be seen at:

http://code.google.com/p/wwwjdic/source/browse/branches/2.0/wwwjdic/src/org/nick/wwwjdic/TtsManager.java