# TextToSpeech.setEngineByPackageName() triggers NullPointerException

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My activity's `onInit()` contains a call to `TextToSpeech.setEngineByPackageName()`:

```
  tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
  tts.setEngineByPackageName("com.ivona.tts.voicebeta.eng.usa.kendra");
```

It works on an Android 2.2.2 device, but on an Android 2.3.4 device it produced a NullPointerException, with the following stack trace:

```
 E/TextToSpeech.java - setEngineByPackageName(3423): NullPointerException
 W/System.err(3423): java.lang.NullPointerException
 W/System.err(3423):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
 W/System.err(3423):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
 W/System.err(3423):    at android.speech.tts.ITts$Stub$Proxy.setEngineByPackageName(ITts.java:654)
 W/System.err(3423):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.setEngineByPackageName(TextToSpeech.java:1356)
```

Since I am providing a hard-coded string parameter, I know that the parameter isn't what's causing the NullPointerException.

I also know that [setEngineByPackageName()](http://hi-android.info/src/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java.html) is deprecated but that's only since API 14, so this couldn't be the reason.

Any idea what could be causing this NullPointerException?

**EDIT**: I wouldn't have been concerned with the "why" if this didn't result in an endless bombardment of:

```
I/TextToSpeech.java(3652): initTts() successfully bound to service
```

Followed by calls to `onInit()` (by the system, not by my code).

My hope is that if I underderstand why this is happening, I can stop the bombardment of `onInit()`s and recover gracefully from the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the TTS engine you are referencing installed on the 2.3.4 device? If it is, it might be a platform bug.

EDIT:
Don't remember what results I got when I did this, but calling `setEngineByPackageName()` when the package doesn't exists is not a good idea. Check if it is installed and don't try to use it if it's not. Something like:

```
boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName) {
  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  try {
    PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);

    return pi != null;
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, the TTS engine I am referencing isn't installed on the 2.3.4 device (CM7). This is part of my effort to bring some robustness to my app by testing for various scenarios and handling the errors. I expected to only handle a situation where the method **doesn't** return `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` but this NullPointerException was totally unexpected. Early versions of TextToSpeech are behaving very inconsistently (just like [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487866/texttospeech-setenginebypackagename-returns-success-even-when-package-is-not-a)) but I must support 2.2

Comment: Now the funny thing is that, on that same 2.3.4 device (CM7, the referenced TTS engine is **NOT** installed), `setEngineByPackageName()` *sometimes* returns SUCCESS. This is insane.

Comment: Don't try to use it if it's not available, see updated answer. All in all, getting this right is rather tricky. See how I (try) to handle it here: http://code.google.com/p/wwwjdic/source/browse/branches/2.0/wwwjdic/src/org/nick/wwwjdic/TtsManager.java

Comment: It's pretty amazing that you already implemented the solution about which I only started to think now. Sometimes working around an incomplete implementation (see quoted comment below) is better than trying to understand what's happening under the cover. :)

Comment: This also solves the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487866/texttospeech-setenginebypackagename-returns-success-even-when-package-is-not-a). If you post the same answer there, I will accept it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to investigate this myself, in case an expert on the subject isn't around:

The NullPointerException stack trace is printed by `setEngineByPackageName()` itself in the catch handler for this try clause:

```
try {
    result = mITts.setEngineByPackageName(enginePackageName);
    if (result == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        mCachedParams[Engine.PARAM_POSITION_ENGINE + 1] = enginePackageName;
    }
}
```

Which suggests that either of the following is null:

1. mITts
2. mCachedParams

mCachedParams is unlikely to be the null one because it is initialized in the constructor. So this leaves us with `mITts`:

If I examine `TextToSpeech.initTts()` I can easily spot 2 points in which mITts can remain null:

1. onServiceConnected()
2. onServiceDisconnected()

But why this is happening only on the 2.3.4 device? This is still a mystery.

Possible clue: The method `TextToSpeech.initTts()` ends with the following comment:

```
mContext.bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
// TODO handle case where the binding works (should always work) but
//      the plugin fails
```

Which may explain why I receive a barrage of `onInit()`s ("initTts() successfully bound to service"): Binding always works, but since the package is not installed, "the plugin fails".

The question now is how to stop this endless loop...