# How to set Portuguese language to TTS engine?

Tags: android

I have one simple application which announces based on the language set in the app. My device supports Portuguese language also but when I set the language in TTS as Portuguese

```
int result = mTts.setLanguage(new Locale("pt");
```

returns always -2 means language is not supported but when I see in device's

> settings-> Language & keyboard->select language

it is having language Portuguese(Portugal).

NOTE: Device's language is English only, I am just setting Application language as Portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

Language support by the Android OS and by the Android TTS engine are two different things.
The [Android Developers API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html) states that TTS is only available in English, French, German, Italian and Spanish.

Comment: it means if I want to support other languages for TTS then I need to install it separately..is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is provided you can find a third party TTS that includes your language of choice. For more info on see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7362534/741249)

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old and since then, Google has launched a huge update of the TTS engine. Now, Portuguese (Brazil) voice is included.

In my app I use:

```
 mTts.setLanguage(new Locale("pt", "POR"));
```

And I see that the device download the data for Portuguese voice (female) and the accent sound very good to me.