# android: is it possible to let the users choose which TTS service provider to use?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My android app is implementing TexttoSpeech services.
I am testing the app using a Samsung device.
By default, it is using the TTS from Google, then one day an alert popped up asking whether to use the Samsung TTS, I have clicked 'yes' and since then I cannot find the Google TTS anymore.

```
12-30 22:03:37.476: I/TextToSpeech(8921): Sucessfully bound to com.samsung.SMT
```

Samsung TTS has a better voice, yet it is reading very slow, significantly delayed, small volume, and boring.

### Question:

My question is that

1. How could I set back the system to use Google TTS?
2. Is there any code to lock the app to use Google TTS and do not pop up messages to ask for installing other providers' TTS services, or at least to let the user make their choice for the TTS services?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362534/how-to-programmtically-change-tts-default-engine

Comment: You can change the default to Google by package name.

Comment: thanks a lot! you have answered my question!

Comment: No problem, I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to Programmtically Change TTS Default Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362534/how-to-programmtically-change-tts-default-engine)

> You can't change the default engine. You can however, change the
>   engine you are using by calling TextToSpeech.setEngineByPackageName()
>   (available since 2.2) or use the constructor that takes an engine
>   package parameter (available in ICS, so not really useful right now).
>
> There is also no API before ICS to find out what engines are
>   installed, so you need to know the other engine's package beforehand
>   to be able to use it.