# Is it available to change TTL(TextToSpeech) engine programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Im developing android application and i'd like to ask something.

As you know, It is available to change TTL engine in configuration manually.
However, what i really want to do is changing TTL engine programmatically.
Unfortunately, I can't find the function for that in TextToSpeech class.
There is only function,"getEngines()", for getting engine which i current use.

Is it available to change TTL(TextToSpeech) engine programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Programmtically Change TTS Default Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362534/how-to-programmtically-change-tts-default-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OS version 14 and up you can use the constructor

```
public TextToSpeech (Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener, String engine)
```

to indicate the engine you want to use.